# Textview didn't expand up to content when back or dismiss from another view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextview

I have UITextView for input the comment of the post. At frist time when this view appear UITextView is working perfectly (Can expand size with content from keyboard input) but if I present or push to next view then dismiss or navigationController.pop for comeback my UITextView didn't expand size with content anymore how I can fix this issue.

My UITextView setup
 - UITextView enable scroll is false.
 - UITextView constrain height I use greater than equal constant 30.

[UITextView expand perfectly]

[image]

[Present PhotoPickerView then dismiss back to fristview UITextView can't expand anymore]

[image]

Comment: what is the view structure?

Comment: MainView I have tableview(layer 1) and commentView(layer 2) at bottom of MainView.

UITextView in CommentView have top and bottom Constraint with Constant 5 of view trailing and leading relation with button photo and post comment.

*CommentView in MainView is UIView with CommentViewClass and didn't set height because i want to CommentView expand height with content